# Energy Smart Meter | Data Feed | In House Display

Tags: meter

Firstly, I am in the UK if that has any relevance on your responses

I have Smart Meters installed by my energy supplier for both Gas and Electric.

They also provide a very basic In House Display (IHD) which shows you how much energy you are using, both real time (well, nearly) and overall daily use.

The thing is that the IHD is so basic and, as a developer, I want to do more and wondered if anyone has come across anything that would allow me to connect to the meter and track the usage myself.

Comment: If you've got details on the exact models of meter that would help; and you may find that your energy suppliers have an API you can connect to.

Comment: IIRC the meter sends an SMS using the standard cellular network to the IHD. Normally, they only provide an IHD when you don't use a phone that can run their app.

Comment: @Neil_UK that depends on the meter, but it might be the way all meters in the UK work, indeed. There's other residential and commercial meters that have their own ISM-band transmission standards. See for example [Hash's works on intercepting smart meter transmission with least cost SDR dongles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYowTR3Dfdk).

Comment: Read the manuals for the devices. You know what devices you use; nobody reading this question would stand a chance of guessing what you use. Site rule: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* <-- this also covers your equipment.